# WiX: How to create file name from a property value

Tags: properties, wix, installation, windows-installer

I have a working WiX installer that correctly writes properties to certain INI files, which works fine, but I have a need to generate the name of an INI file on the fly, from the computer name, eg.

**MACHINE(xxx).INI**

where xxx is my computer name.

I have tried all sorts of combinations of properties and I just can't seem to get it working. Can anyone put me right ?

This is my latest attempt that doesn't work:

```
<Property Id="MACHINEINI" Value="MACHINE([%COMPUTERNAME]).ini" />
...
<IniFile Id="IniPermissions"
    Directory="MYDIR"
    Action="addLine"
    Name="[MACHINEINI]"
    Section="[ComputerName]"
    Key="Permissions"
    Value="TEST" />
```

I never see the value of MACHINEINI, as the filename that gets created is actually called

[MACHINEINI]

The value it writes in is correct, so I see the contents as follows:

> [xxx] Permissions=TEST

(where xxx is my machine name)

I have tried using [ComputerName], [COMPUTERNAME], [%COMPUTERNAME]

When I build the installer, I get the following error:

> C:\Source\blah\BLAH.wxs(50) : warning CNDL1077 : The 'MACHINEINI' Pro
>   perty contains '[COMPUTERNAME]' in its value which is an illegal
>   reference to an other property.  If this value is a string literal,
>   not a property reference, pl ease ignore this warning.  To set a
>   property with the value of another property,  use a CustomAction with
>   Property and Value attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying Windows Installer table doesn't support this.  Note that the FileName column is of type FileName.  Only the Formatted type can take a [PROPERTY].

[IniFile Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369282%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You could need a custom action to write temporary records to the IniFile table to transform the file name.  The advantage versus using a custom action to literally write the INI file is that rollback would be automatically handled for you.

It's not possible to tell you how to do this exactly since I don't know what language you'd want to use to write the custom action.

A simpler approach (from the installers perspective)  would be to transform the [KEY] name inside a single INI instead of writing to different INI files.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I haven't used custom actions before, but I guess I'm going to have to do it. I don't really have a choice about the name of the INI, since there is a large amount of legacy code using it, and I'm just trying to build a new installer for it.

I would write a custom action in whatever language was easier (although I mainly develop in C# on Windows)

Comment: WiX has something called DTF for writing managed custom actions.  You'll find articles on my blog http://blog.iswix.com, on Google and StackOverflow.

Comment: Here's example of dynamic authored MSI using DTF albeit a different table: http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2008/07/dynamic-windows-installer-ui.html

Comment: Thanks, I used a custom action and have it all working nicely now.